# Counters are initialized every time?

Tags: haskell

I try to make a simple counter. My counters do not go up however. It seems to me as if they are re-initialized every time by the function "inc" or maybe the (n+1) does not work. How do I best fix this?

```
inc :: Int -> IO Int
inc n = return (n+1)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let c = 0
  let f = 0
  putStrLn "Starting..."
  conn <- connect "192.168.35.62" 8081
  time $
    forM_ [0..10000] $ \i -> do
      p <- ping conn "ping"
      if p=="pong" then inc c
         else inc f
  printf "Roundtrips %d\n" (c::Int)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Though mutable variables can be used in Haskell as shown by other commenters, it is not a good style: mutation should not be used in most cases.

The `inc` function accepts its argument by value, that is, it doesn't modify its argument. Also, the variables declared by `let` keep their initial values, so you cannot change them.

How do you write if no variable can ever be changed? The answer is:

1. instead of modifying something in-place, return a new value
2. for loops, use recursion

Fortunately, you rarely need to write recursion yourself, as most of recursive patterns are already in the standard library.

In your case you need to perform several IO actions and return the final value of the two counters. Let's start from one action:

```
let tryOnePing (c, f) i = do
    p <- ping conn "ping"
    return $ if p == "pong" then (c+1, f) else (c, f+1)
```

Here we declare a local function with 2 parameters: the current values of the counters, packed in a tuple `(Int, Int)` (a structure in other languages) and current iteration `Int`. The function performs IO actions and returns modified values of the counters `IO (Int, Int)`. This all is indicated in its type:

```
tryOnePing :: (Int, Int) -> Int -> IO (Int, Int)
```

`ping` returns a value of `IO String` type. To compare it, you need a `String` without `IO`. To do that, you should use `>>=` function:

```
let tryOnePing (c, f) i = ping conn "ping" >>= \p -> {process the string somehow}
```

As this pattern is common, it can be written like this

```
let tryOnePing (c, f) i = do
    p <- ping conn "ping"
    {process the string somehow}
```

But the meaning is exactly the same (compiler translates `do` notation into applications of `>>=`).

The processing shows a few more common patterns:

```
if p == "pong" then (c+1, f) else (c, f+1)
```

Here `if` is not an imperative `if` but more like a ternary `condition ? value1 : value2` operator in other languages. Also note, that our `tryOnePing` function accepts (c, f) and returns either `(c+1, f)` or `(c, f+1)`. We used tuples as we need to work only with 2 counters. In case of big number of counters, we would need to declare a structure type and use named fields.

The value of the whole If construct is a tuple (Int, Int). `ping` is an IO action, so `tryOnePing` must be an IO action too. The `return` function is not an imperative return but a way to convert `(Int, Int)` to `IO (Int, Int)`.

So, as we have tryOnePing, we need to write a loop to run it 1000 times. Your `forM_` was not a good choice:

1. It doesn't pass our two counters between iterations
2. `_` indicates that it throws the final value of the counters away instead of returning it

You need here not `forM_` but `foldM`

```
foldM tryOnePing (0, 0) [0 .. 10000]
```

`foldM` performs an IO action parametrized by each element of the list and passes some state between iterations, in our case the two counters. It accepts the initial state, and returns the final state. Of course, as its performs IO actions, it returns IO (Int, Int), so we need to use `>>=` to extract it again for displaying:

```
foldM tryOnePing (0, 0) [0 .. 10000] >>= \(c, f) -> print (c, f)
```

In Haskell, you can perform so called 'eta reductions', that is you can remove same identifiers from both sides of a function declaration. E.g. `\foo -> bar foo` is the same as just `bar`. So in this case with `>>=` you can write:

```
foldM tryOnePing (0, 0) [0 .. 10000] >>= print
```

which is much shorter than `do` notation:

```
 do
   (c, f) <- foldM tryOnePing (0, 0) [0 .. 10000]
   print (c, f)
```

Also note that you don't need to have two counters: if you have 3000 successes then you have 7000 failures. So the code becomes:

```
main = do
    conn <- connect "192.168.35.62" 8081
    let tryOnePing c i = do
        p <- ping conn "ping"
        return $ if p == "pong" then c+1 else c
    c <- foldM tryOnePing 0 [0 .. 10000]
    print (c, 10000 - c)
```

Finally, in Haskell its good to separate IO actions from non-IO code. So it's better to collect all results from pings into a list and then to count successful pings in it:

```
main = do
    conn <- connect "192.168.35.62" 8081
    let tryOnePing i = ping conn "ping"
    pings <- mapM tryOnePing [0 .. 10000]
    let c = length $ filter (\ping -> ping == "pong") pings
    print (c, 10000 - c)
```

Note that we avoided incrementing altogether.

It can be written even shorter, but requires more skill to read and write. Don't worry, you will learn these tricks soon:

```
main = do
    conn <- connect "192.168.35.62" 8081
    c <- fmap (length . filter (== "pong")) $ mapM (const $ ping conn "ping") [0 .. 10000]
    print (c, 10000 - c)
```

Comment: Thanks! To my "defense" I must say that I know about immutability. However, I found the "n+1" here: 

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/1.1.0.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html

and here

http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/goodies.html


and was wondering of it could work. Since it compiled I thought, - wooow, this works. Do these ticks aim to solve the same problem, counters that is?

Comment: Thanks. By the way: when timing the snippet from answer #1 w IORefs I get half the runtime compared to timing `pings <- time (mapM tryOnePing [0 .. 1000000])`. I assume that in the first case it does not wait the waiting time for the responses into the timing. Could that have to do w the lazy nature or could it be that this IORef construct executes faster??

Comment: It could be both. Use profiling and/or look at generated lower-level haskell core language to see. Also use -O2 as my shorter code relies heavily on the presence of optimizations.

Comment: As for state monad you mentioned - yes, it is there to solve the counters problem too.

Comment: This mapM thing, is will that still be feasible if the number of pings is set to 10 million or will then effects such as memory consumption make this a sub-optimal choice?

Comment: With optimizations on it should be feasible. The `[0 .. 10000]` thing defines a huge list of numbers, so all the examples rely on the elimination of intermediate lists by Haskell optimizer.

Answer (score 7):

In Haskell data are immutable by default. This means that the `c` in `inc c` is always zero.

To get mutable variables in Haskell, you have to ask for them *explicitly*, i.e. by using [IORefs](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0-latest/html/libraries/base-4.3.1.0/Data-IORef.html). Using them you could write something like:

```
import Data.IORef

inc :: IORef Int -> IO ()
inc ref = modifyIORef ref (+1)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  c <- newIORef 0
  f <- newIORef 0
  putStrLn "Starting..."
  conn <- connect "192.168.35.62" 8081
  time $
    forM_ [0..10000] $ \i -> do
      p <- ping conn "ping"
      if p=="pong" 
         then inc c
         else inc f
  c' <- readIORef c
  printf "Roundtrips %d\n" c'
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. I will read up on this. One more problem w the code is that it reports a runtime of e.g. 2sec but runs 15sec until it returns to the console :-(. But thanks for your solution, that is great help.

Comment: IORefs here are not idiomatic and a bad style. Mutable variables are not required to implement the task he wants to.

Answer (score 5):

Just like in code outside of `IO`, you can string together a series of computations using a fold.  [`foldM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v:foldM) operates within a monad, e.g.

```
main = do
    conn <- connect "192.168.35.62" 8081
    let tryOnePing (c, f) i = do
        p <- ping conn "ping"
        return $ if p == "pong" then (c+1, f) else (c, f+1)
    (c, f) <- foldM tryOnePing (0, 0) [0 .. 10000]
    print (c, f)
```

Comment: I would guess that `foldM` is beyond the available understanding of the OP at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Variables are immutable in Haskell.  When you call `inc f` it returns a value of `0 + 1` which you promptly ignore.  The value of `f` is `0` and will remain so for all time.