# How can I refactor this without IORefs?

Tags: haskell, refactoring, ioref

How could I refactor this so that eventually IORefs would not be necessary?

```
inc :: IORef Int -> IO ()
inc ref = modifyIORef ref (+1)

main = withSocketsDo $ do
        s <- socket AF_INET Datagram defaultProtocol
        c <- newIORef 0
        f <- newIORef 0
        hostAddr <- inet_addr host
        time $ forM [0 .. 10000] $ \i -> do
              sendAllTo s (B.pack  "ping") (SockAddrInet port hostAddr)
              (r, _) <- recvFrom s 1024 
              if (B.unpack r) == "PING" then (inc c) else (inc f)
        c' <- readIORef c
        print (c')
        sClose s
        return()
```

Comment: I think this was already answered before. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219222/counters-are-initialized-every-time - the code didn't change too much since that time, so old answers are still applicable

Comment: There problem here is that in order to apply the solution you refer to I would probably need to put all valid (B.unpack r) in a list. Something like r : [r] or so. However, all constructs I tried fail for different reason. An other issue is that it would be great to get along with forM_ (in the above example possible) since this runs twice as fast.

Comment: You can use the `foldM` solution from there http://stackoverflow.com/a/8219503/805266 - it should be as fast as `forM_`. Just try it and show us what went wrong.

Comment: @nponeccop THANKs for this very helpful teaching. Generally I tend to get a "Stackspace overflow" during runtime for numbers bigger than 500K.

Comment: Then you should state so in the question. Solving space leaks is much more interesting than just helping another guy to write monadic code, so you may attract more answers by making your question more challenging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with using IORefs here? You're in IO anyways with the networking operations. IORefs aren't always the cleanest solution, but they seem to do the job well in this case.

Regardless, for the sake of answering the question, let's remove the IORefs. These references serve as a way of keeping state, so we'll have to come up with an alternate way to keep the stateful information.

The pseudocode for what we want to do is this:

```
open the connection
10000 times: 
  send a message
  receive the response
  (keep track of how many responses are the message "PING")
print how many responses were the message "PING"
```

The chunk that is indented under `1000 times` can be abstracted into its own function. If we are to avoid IORefs, then this function will have to take in a previous state and produce a next state.

```
main = withSocketsDo $ do
  s <- socket AF_INET Datagram defaultProtocol
  hostAddr <- inet_addr host
  let sendMsg = sendAllTo s (B.pack  "ping") (SockAddrInet port hostAddr)
      recvMsg = fst `fmap` recvFrom s 1024
  (c,f) <- ???
  print c
  sClose s
```

So the question is this: what do we put at the `???` place? We need to define some way to "perform" an IO action, take its result, and modify state with that result somehow. We also need to know how many times to do it.

```
 performRepeatedlyWithState :: a             -- some state
                            -> IO b          -- some IO action that yields a value
                            -> (a -> b -> a) -- some way to produce a new state
                            -> Int           -- how many times to do it
                            -> IO a          -- the resultant state, as an IO action
 performRepeatedlyWithState s _ _ 0 = return s
 performRepeatedlyWithState someState someAction produceNewState timesToDoIt = do
   actionresult <- someAction
   let newState = produceNewState someState actionResult
   doWithState newState someAction produceNewState (pred timesToDoIt)
```

All I did here was write down the type signature that matched what I said above, and produced the relatively obvious implementation. I gave everything a very verbose name to hopefully make it apparent exactly what this function means. Equipped with this simple function, we just need to use it.

```
let origState = (0,0)
    action = ???
    mkNewState = ???
    times = 10000
(c,f) <- performRepeatedlyWithState origState action mkNewState times
```

I've filled in the easy parameters here. The original state is `(c,f) = (0,0)`, and we want to perform this 10000 times. (Or is it 10001?) But what should `action` and `mkNewState` look like? The `action` should have type `IO b`; it's some IO action that produces *something*.

```
action = sendMsg >> recvMsg
```

I bound `sendMsg` and `recvMsg` to expressions from your code earlier. The action we want to perform is to send a message, and then receive a message. The value this action produces is the message received.

Now, what should `mkNewState` look like? It should have the type `a -> b -> a`, where `a` is the type of the State, and `b` is the type of the action result.

```
mkNewState (c,f) val = if (B.unpack val) == "PING"
                         then (succ c, f)
                         else (c, succ f)
```

This isn't the cleanest solution, but do you get the general idea? You can replace IORefs by writing a function that recursively calls itself, passing extra parameters along in order to keep track of state. The exact same idea is embodied in the [foldM solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219222/counters-are-initialized-every-time/8219503#8219503) suggested on the similar question.

Bang patterns, as Nathan Howell suggests, would be wise, to avoid building up a large thunk of `succ (succ (succ ...)))` in your state:

```
mkNewState (!c, !f) val = ...
```

Comment: IORefs are 'wrong' because they are non-idiomatic and an overkill here. Such simple code doesn't require any mutation.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the earlier comment regarding a stack overflow.

The accumulators 'f' and 'c' in either the IORef or foldM case need to be evaluated to prevent a long chain of thunks from being allocated while you're iterating. One way of forcing evaluation of the thunks is to use a bang pattern. This tells the compiler to evaluate the value, removing the thunk, even though it's value is not demanded in the function.

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad
import Data.ByteString.Char8
import Data.Foldable (foldlM)
import Data.IORef
import Network.Socket hiding (recvFrom)
import Network.Socket.ByteString (recvFrom, sendAllTo)

main = withSocketsDo $ do
  let host = "127.0.0.1"
      port= 9898

  s <- socket AF_INET Datagram defaultProtocol
  hostAddr <- inet_addr host
  -- explicitly mark both accumulators as strict using bang patterns
  let step (!c, !f) i = do
        sendAllTo s "PING" (SockAddrInet port hostAddr)
        (r, _) <- recvFrom s 1024 
        return $ case r of
          -- because c and f are never used, the addition operator below
          -- builds a thunk chain. these can lead to a stack overflow
          -- when the chain is being evalulated by the 'print c' call below.
          "PING" -> (c+1, f)
          _      -> (c, f+1)
  (c, f) <- foldlM step (0, 0) [0..10000]
  print c
  sClose s
  return ()
```

Comment: You write: "because c and f are never used". I do not understand this part of your answer. Why are they never used?

Comment: :-( does not compile in my case. I get the error "Illegal bang-pattern (use -XBangPatterns)". Is that an option I need to add or does that mean I need to re-cimple GHC or so?

Comment: @JFritsch - did you put `{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}` at the top of the file? And are you using a recent GHC?

Comment: @JFritsch they are never demanded. The values need to be used in a pattern (the left side of an equals sign), with a pattern guard or by calling a function that is strict. Instead the compiler (typically) decides to allocate a thunk, and in the case of a fold or for loop this can cause a stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks. Added the lines. I get now this infamous "The last statement in a 'do' construct must be an expression". No matter what pseudo code I add to make the do construct complete (e.g. print ("test") it always complains about the same :-(.

Comment: Found it. Brackets were missing around the case block.